# Deleting a parent record in PostgreSQL when deleting a child if there is a foreign key from the parent record to the child

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Friends, hello everyone. We faced a problem at work that we couldn't solve. It became clear that simple
there is no solution, so we decided to ask the advice of more experienced people on the forum.

1. We have a PostgreSQL database and we work with it using the SqlAlchemy python framework using its ORM
2. We have an entity that can be represented as:

```
    {   
        uuid: UUID
        data: {
            property_1: {
                value: str
            }
            property_2: {
                value: str
            }
            property_3: {
                value: str
            }
        }
    }
```

or as multiple nested entities

```
    Main
    {   
        uuid: UUID
        data: Data
    }


    Data
    {
        property_1: Property
        property_2: Property
        property_3: Property
    }


    Property
    {
        value: str
    }
```

3. We have three tables that allow us to store such an entity

```
    main_table
    {
        id: int
        uuid: UUID  
    }


    data_table
    {
        id: int
        main_id: int = ForeignKey (main_table.id)
        property_1_id: ForeignKey (property_table.id)
        property_2_id: ForeignKey (property_table.id)
        property_3_id: ForeignKey (property_table.id)
    }


    property_table
    {
        id: int
        value: str
    }
```

It can be seen that the second table contains several columns of the same type (Property)

It turns out such a relationship by foreign keys between tables:

```
    main_table <--- data_table ---> property_table
```

If you poison an entity into the database, then it will correctly decompose into tables, while reading everything is also correctly assembled from tables into one object.

**BUT there is a problem with the removal!**
For ForeignKey in data_table ON DELETE CASCADE is set, so when we delete a record in main_table, the record in data_table is automatically deleted, and the records in property_table remain garbage, because they do not refer to the record in data_table, but vice versa, so there is a cascade deletion does not work.

**Question. On the face of it, this is a fairly typical task, but we have not yet encountered this. I ask to prompt an approach or approaches in the decision.
We need to be able to delete the entire entity, that is, records in all tables associated with the entity. In other words, when deleting an entry in main_table, all entries associated with it from the data and property tables are deleted**

Thank you in advance!

I tried to use ON DELETE CASCADE but figured out that it can't work with such relation direction. It works only for deleting the entry that has a foreign key to another entry when deleting this another one

Comment: `ON DELETE SET NULL`? You don't say what you want to happen when you delete the property

Comment: @RichardHuxton Property will be not deleted separatelly.  So it  should be deleted like part of whole eintity. That the point.

Comment: @python_user thanks, but i we use sqlalchemy and I didn'g find any about triggers there

Comment: @python_user i've started reading yourt answer! thanks! i will reply after applying  your advices

Comment: @python_user it is good way to solve the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like a conceptual / design issue.

Why are you storing values in separate table if they are not unique?

If the `property_table.value` attribute does not make sense without corresponding record in `data_table`, it should not be stored in a separate table.

Each object in your model should have a natural (aka "business") key, not only an artificial key.

Maybe the model is "over-normalized"? Why not keep values in data_table?